# Get text file to useble dataframe R

Tags: r

I am trying to read a .txt file from the internet and get it into a useable form in R. Seems like it should be easy, but I am struggling:

Data is from Berkeley Earth:

```
b_earth_url <- 'http://berkeleyearth.lbl.gov/auto/Global/Land_and_Ocean_complete.txt'
```

I have tried the following:

```
read.table(b_earth_url, sep = '\t', comment.char = '%', row.names = NULL)
```

or:

```
b_earth_data <- readLines(b_earth_url)[!grepl('%', readLines(b_earth_url))] 
data.frame(b_earth_data, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I have tried a few other options, but can't get past a dataframe with a single variable, containing a fixed width chr vector.

I have tried `extract()`, `separate()` and `strsplit()`, and can't get any of them to work. I don't think I know how to use a fixed width separator for `sep =`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The separator is whitespace (blanks) not tabs:

```
out <- read.table(b_earth_url, comment.char = '%')
head(out)
#     V1 V2     V3    V4     V5    V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12
# 1 1850  1 -0.781 0.382    NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
# 2 1850  2 -0.260 0.432    NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
# 3 1850  3 -0.399 0.348    NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
# 4 1850  4 -0.696 0.296    NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
# 5 1850  5 -0.690 0.320    NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
# 6 1850  6 -0.392 0.228 -0.529 0.147 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```